# Updating the text of a large number of stored procedures

Tags: t-sql

The question pretty much sums it up.  I've got to replace text in a large number for store procedures.  Its not so many that doing it manually is impossible, but enough that I'm asking the question.  I also prefer automation as it reduces the change of user error when we make the change in production.

I can Identify them like this:

```
select OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id), *
from sys.procedures
where OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) like '%''MyExampleLiteral''%'
order by name
```

Is there any way to mass update them all to change 'MyExampleLiteral' to 'MyOtherExampleLiteral'?

I'd even settle for a way to open all the stored procs.  Just Finding these store procs in a larger list will take some time.

I thought about generating alter statements using the above select statements, but then I lose line breaks.

Thanks in advance,

This is a Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Is using Visual Studio an option? Visual Studio has some nice features that would assist with this change.

Comment: No... I don't think I could use Visual Studio.  I have it on a development environment, but cannot access the test or production databases from a server with VS installed.

Comment: On ssms, generate a script for all stored procs to a new query window and then use ctrl+f to get find and replace window. Select options as required. I think that will do the job.

Comment: Kaf, That's the brute force way of doing it.  Just trying to spare myself a few hours of work, and the potential for making an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are different tools to use depending on the database in question.  For example,  Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools integrates with Visual Studio, and allows you to do these types of operations fairly easily.  The database is stored in your solution as scripts, which you can then search and replace any keyword you wish.  I'm assuming there would be similar tools available for other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with dynamic sql. Query the system tables to get all the SPs containing your "MyExampleLiteral":

```
SELECT [object_id] FROM sys.objects o
WHERE type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
    AND is_ms_shipped = 0 
    AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.[object_id]) LIKE '%<search string>%'
```

Then, write a while loop to go through those object_ids. In the while loop, get the `OBJECT_DEFINITION()` into a string and replace the "MyExampleLiteral", then replace `CREATE PROCEDURE` with `ALTER PROCEDURE` and execute the string using `sp_executesql`.

Doing something this crazy, make sure you backup the database first.